# ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
fs.unlink('backup/' + 'test')
```

I get an error when deleting a folder:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'backup/test']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: 'backup/test' }
```

I tried to set the rights to the remote directory correctly. but it did not help.

here is the path to this folder app.set('backup', path.join(__dirname, '../backup'));

What is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: is backup located in the directory you are executing `fs.unlink` ?

Comment: this is not a backup located

Comment: you have to specify the path where backup is located

Comment: I just want to delete the folder that is on this path  'backup/test'

Comment: does the path "backup/test" exist in your current working directory

Comment: Yes, it exists in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
const path = require('path');
fs.unlink(path.join(app.settings.backup, 'test'));
```

Comment: yes.  but it did not help.here is the path to this folder
 `app.set('backup', path.join(__dirname, '../backup'));
`